# What is the "correct" order of rel and href in a link element?

Tags: html, css

When using `<link>` elements in the head of a HTML document, is the attribute `rel` or the attribute `href` supposed to come first? Functionally, they don't differ (as far as I know), but is there a standard of how they're "supposed" to be done? Looking at other peoples websites, it seems to be a 50/50 chance that its done either way.

IE:

```html
<head>
 <link href="./assets/favicon.png" rel="icon">
 <link href="./assets/foo.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Vs.

```html
<head>
 <link rel="icon" href="./assets/favicon.png">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/foo.css">
</head>
```

If it's just a preference thing and there is no standard, thanks anyways :)

Comment: Preference, order does not matter.

Comment: the way I see it, this is an opinionated question, I personally prefer the first way to do

Comment: It makes no difference to anything what order they appear in

Answer (score -2):

I think the second option that rel  is first than href is the best where you will give a higher SEO rating and have your website in the beginning

Comment: It should be a comment